# How do I properly setup javamail to use STARTTLS?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, starttls

When setting up my session I am setting the starttls.enable and .required properties but when the connection happens it should fail according to the documentation:

> mail.smtp.starttls.enable  boolean  If true, enables the use of the STARTTLS command (if supported by the server) to switch the connection to a TLS-protected connection before issuing any login commands. Note that an appropriate trust store must configured so that the client will trust the server's certificate. Defaults to false."
>   http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

```
props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtps.host", MAILSERV);
props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", 465);
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtps.port", 465);
props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class","utils.DummySSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);  


transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect(mailServer, port, username, password);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

So what am I doing wrong that is allowing me to use Starttls when its not supported by the server?

Comment: "Note that if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*".", you seem to be using port 465, which is usually SMTP over SSL. Although, I'm not even sure if you can do STARTTLS on top of smtps

Comment: I think you are correct. After defaulting everything to "smtp" instead of "smtps", I am getting  the desired results. I really do not like using properties for this reason.

Comment: You can get rid of those socket factory properties too, [you don't need them](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I was having with STARTTLS was caused by me getting a secure transport:

```
transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

After changing it to "smtp" i was able to use STARTTLS.